# Configuration overrides have unpredictable results

Tags: configuration, 9

I'm setting up configuration splits with Drupal 9 and encountering unexpected results.

None of my splits are marked as Active in the active configuration or the exported configuration YAML.

I want to set the default Local split in `settings.php` and then use `settings.local.php` to override it on `dev`, `stg`, `prd` environments.

My local development environment is DDEV-Local v1.17.5. The three remote environments are all set up on one remote server in the client's private AWS, in three different Apache VirtualHosts.

I can't use environment variables to differentiate the `dev`, `stg`, `prd` environments since they are all on one host. It's been a challenge differentiating the environments without the usual Acquia or Pantheon environment variables.

(Note: I understand if `config_split` is off-topic here since it is not a core module. I have created [an issue queue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split/issues/3218362), but I'm still hoping that someone will see the question here and offer an insight.)

This is the default override in `settings.php`:

```php
  $config['config_split.config_split.local']['status'] = TRUE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.prd']['status'] = FALSE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.stg']['status'] = FALSE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.dev']['status'] = FALSE;
```

So far, so good. The Local split is "active (overwritten)".

Things get weird when I edit this to enable another split in my Local environment:

```php
  $config['config_split.config_split.local']['status'] = FALSE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.prd']['status'] = TRUE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.stg']['status'] = FALSE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.dev']['status'] = FALSE;
```

After editing `settings.php` (and clearing cache, of course) the Production split is "active (overwritten)", as expected.

Unfortunately, the Local split is also "active (overwritten)" despite setting its `['status'] = FALSE;`,

Things get weirder when I attempt to logically negate the values of all the splits:

```php
  $config['config_split.config_split.local']['status'] = FALSE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.prd']['status'] = TRUE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.stg']['status'] = TRUE;
  $config['config_split.config_split.dev']['status'] = TRUE;
```

Now, the Local split is *still* "active (overwritten)" despite setting its `['status'] = FALSE;`,

The Stage and Production splits are "active (overwritten)" to match their `['status'] = TRUE;`,

And the Dev split remains "inactive" despite setting its `['status'] = TRUE;`,

Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the machine names of the splits (e.g., `dev_split`) and everything works as expected.

Therefore, the problem was being caused by the `acquia/blt` package, which uses the `acquia/drupal-environment-detector` package to set the active split based on Acquia environment variables.

Since `$_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT']` is unset, the Local environment split will always be active.

I'm not sure why the Dev split cannot be activated, but that is probably related as well.

I could remove BLT from the project entirely since we are not using Acquia hosting, and therefore we are no longer using it for much, but I was reluctant to set up the automated testing stuff again without all that Robo goodness.

Instead, I made `acquia/blt` a Composer dev dependency so it would not be installed in higher environments. Apparently, that was not enough -- it still messes with my config splits, and may have other unpredictable side effects.

The quick fix is to change machine names for splits. Probably ditching BLT altogether is a better solution in the long run.

Closed (works as intended)

P.S.: If your BLT project is hosted on Acquia, then the environment detection will work correctly, and this problem will not arise. No wonder this is such a rare problem -- most people probably do not use BLT outside of Acquia's environments.

Comment: I have been dealing with BLT lately, and yes the settings includes (along with the Acquia ones) makes it rather confusing.  Additionally, unless you create your own detector there is only [dev, stage, prod, ci, ode, ah_other, local]  - EnvironmentDetector#getEnvironments